# Animate 3D array 'layer by layer'

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib

I have a 3-dimensional np array with binary data. It was created from multiple 2-dimensional arrays 'stacked' along the 3rd axis.

In an matplotlib animation i want to show the 2-dimensional arrays 'layer by layer'. I've found out that i can plot one (the first) layer via:

```
plt.imshow(data[:, :, 0], cmap='binary')
```

Unfortunately i'm new to all things matplotlib related, so i do not know how to update the shown data (or switch the shown 'layer') in the animation.

Can someone tell me how to change the plotted layer so that every one gets shown in the animation?

Comment: The only difference of your case compared to the one in the linked duplicate is that you already have a "list" of images. I.e. you need to animate over the array `data[:,:,j]` where `j` is the animating variable.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you i did not see this answer. Unfortunately i get a 'IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 5' when my array has a shape of (x, y, 5) after some animation frames.

Comment: Of course you can only animate as many "layers" as you have (in this case probably 5). So `frames` can only be 5 or less.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you so much for clarification!